# In MUI-Datatables how do I retain the table title when the table is printed?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

When I print the table using the print icon only the table header and columns get printed. How do I also print the table title.[Image of table title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3jWF.png)

Comment: This is the library: https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables